# Boost::asio::windows::stream_handle client side don't get a data

Tags: winapi, boost-asio

I try to use windows pipes with asio::windows::stream_handle but I get an ununderstood behaviour for me: client side don't catch transfered data, but server side don't launch a handler of async_write. My code is below. Client and Server are two differrent processes, their binaries are in the same directory.

Server:

```
    class MessageProcessor
    {
    private:
        HANDLE m_WindowsPipeHandle;
        OVERLAPPED m_OverlapWin;
        std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::windows::stream_handle> m_Pipe;
    public:
        MessageProcessor(boost::asio::io_context& asio_ctx, const std::string& pipe_name)
        {
            if (std::filesystem::exists(pipe_name))
            {
                std::filesystem::remove(pipe_name);
            }

            m_WindowsPipeHandle = CreateNamedPipe(
              pipe_name.c_str(),
              PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND | FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
              PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
              PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
              1,
              1,
              INFINITE,
              NULL);

           if (m_WindowsPipeHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
           {
               assert(false && "Pipe");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
           if (ConnectNamedPipe(m_WindowsPipeHandle, &m_OverlapWin) != 0)
           {
               assert(false && "Connect Pipe");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }

           std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
           m_Pipe = std::make_unique<boost::asio::windows::stream_handle>(asio_ctx, m_WindowsPipeHandle);
        }

        void AsyncWrite(const std::string& msg)
        {
            log("Launch async transfer", msg);
            boost::asio::async_write(
              *m_Pipe,
              boost::asio::buffer(msg),
              [](const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
              {
                  if (error)
                  {
                      log("Pipe transfer error", error);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      log("Pipe transfer ok", bytes_transferred);
                  }
              });
         }
    };
```

AsynWrite is called defered by asio::post via timer

Client:

```
class Pipe
{
private:
    HANDLE win_handle;
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::windows::stream_handle> pipe;
    std::string read_buf;

    std::fstream fs;

public:
    Pipe()
    {
        fs.open("tester.txt", std::ios_base::out);
        win_handle = CreateFile(
            cfg::PipeName.c_str(),
            GENERIC_READ,
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
            NULL);

        if (win_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            assert(false && "Pipe Client");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        pipe = std::make_unique<boost::asio::windows::stream_handle>(ctx, win_handle);
    }

    void Run()
    {
        fs << "Run launch" << std::endl;
        boost::asio::async_read(
            *pipe,
            boost::asio::buffer(read_buf),
            [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes)
            {
                if (error)
                {
                    fs << error << std::endl;
                }
                if (!read_buf.empty())
                {
                    fs << "Readed str: " << read_buf << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    fs << "Empty buf!" << std::endl;
                }

                boost::asio::post(ctx, boost::bind(&Pipe::Run, this));
            });
    }
};
```

It writes 'Empty buf' always :(

May be who knows, why my server doesn't real transfer data via win pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boost::asio::buffer(read_buf)
```

According to the [docs](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload27.html)

> Create a new modifiable buffer that represents the given string.
>
> ```
> template<
>     typename Elem,
>     typename Traits,
>     typename Allocator>
> mutable_buffer buffer(
>     std::basic_string< Elem, Traits, Allocator > & data);
> ```
>
> ##### Return Value
>
> mutable_buffer(data.size() ? &data[0] : 0, data.size() * sizeof(Elem)).
>
> ##### Remarks
>
> The buffer is invalidated by any non-const operation called on the
> given string object.

So you're explicitly creating a buffer with length zero. There's no space in the buffer, which is a [completion condition for `async_read`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html).

You can pre-size the buffer:

```
std::string buf;
std::cout << boost::asio::buffer(buf).size() << std::endl;

buf.assign("Hello world!");
std::cout << boost::asio::buffer(buf).size() << std::endl;

buf.resize(1024);
std::cout << boost::asio::buffer(buf).size() << std::endl;
```

Prints

```
0
12
1024
```

If you want a growing buffer you need to use a `DynamicBuffer` model. E.g. `streambuf` or `dynamic_string_buffer` etc. A creative example:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/023b7742b879ae9f)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::string_view_literals;
namespace asio = boost::asio;

namespace {
    auto poem = R"(
        I went to send a missive today
        As I have done so oft before
        But I forgot to employ that scrap of advice
        "Use Signal. Use Tor."

    )"sv;

    float constexpr crypto[]{
        1.3563156e-19, 1.3563156e-19, 1.692641e+22,  1.7563698e+25,
        1.6611423e+22, 6.7120163e+22, 4.2902826e+24, 4.524393e+30,
        8.398558e-33,  1.3563156e-19, 1.3563156e-19, -2.0796537e-38,
        1.2414338e+28, 1.271254e+31,  7.270847e+31,  1.1258676e+24,
        2.028251e-19,  7.3782448e+28, 1.172262e-19,  1.3563156e-19,
        10.007843,     7.316806e+34,  1.8466762e+20, 7.316806e+34,
        1.8466762e+20, 7.316806e+34,  1.8466762e+20, 7.316806e+34,
        1.3555985e-19, 1.3563156e-19, 1.6885541e+31, 1.595227e+25,
        1.0901187e+27, 1.6885558e+31, 6.5649985e+28, 9.35016e-40};

    auto signature = R"(
                 Manish Goregaokar 2017
    )"sv;
} // namespace

template <typename DynBuf> void foo(DynBuf&& buf) {
    std::array src{
        asio::buffer(poem),
        asio::buffer(crypto),
        asio::buffer(signature),
    };
    for (auto in : src) {
        for (; auto n = asio::buffer_copy(buf.prepare(90), in); in += n) {
            buf.commit(n);
            std::cout << "Read " << n << " bytes\n";
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string s;

    foo(asio::dynamic_buffer(s));

    asio::streambuf sb;
    foo(sb);

    std::cout << s.length() << " == " << sb.in_avail() << "\n"
              << s << "\n-----\n"
              << &sb;
}
```

Prints

```
Read 90 bytes
Read 75 bytes
Read 90 bytes
Read 54 bytes
Read 45 bytes
Read 90 bytes
Read 75 bytes
Read 90 bytes
Read 54 bytes
Read 45 bytes
444 == 354

        I went to send a missive today
        As I have done so oft before
        But I forgot to employ that scrap of advice
        "Use Signal. Use Tor."

            Heed this advice, children.
        It’s not something to ignore
        Always, always, always, always
        Use Signal. Use Tor.
                 Manish Goregaokar 2017
    
-----

        I went to send a missive today
        As I have done so oft before
        But I forgot to employ that scrap of advice
        "Use Signal. Use Tor."

            Heed this advice, children.
        It’s not something to ignore
        Always, always, always, always
        Use Signal. Use Tor.
                 Manish Goregaokar 2017
```

Full poem here: https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/03/12/use-signal-use-tor/

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention this: Consider using Boost Process that supports interprocess pipes  portably. It might make your life easier. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/process.html

Comment: How I understood, async_pipe works only with related processes :(. I tried to use it, one pipe file for writing and for reading, from my unrelated processes and I got an error (mkinfo() error). It happened because I use one pipe with the same name, how I understood. But Boost.Process doesn't support it.
If I am not right, please, tell me :)

Comment: Wait. I'm confused. You're on windows. P{resumably you meant [`mkfifo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/mkfifo.html) which is only part of the [POSIX implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/process/blob/develop/include/boost/process/detail/posix/async_pipe.hpp#L201). The Windows implementation doesn't: https://github.com/boostorg/process/blob/develop/include/boost/process/detail/windows/async_pipe.hpp#L285

Comment: Yeah, you are right about `mkfifo` and POSIX implementation. When I used async_pipe I thought it is OS independent instrument and I launched my program on Unix-like.
But, could you help me still one time? I try to use async_pipe, writing works well, but reading don't. [Code](https://pastebin.com/Ha3Asy48) is only for reading. Handler isn't called. With `stream_handle` this code works

Comment: @fenixD With some small changes, works for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7524e2be2c10013a see local demo - note the interaction with other readers! https://imgur.com/3Sh9A9s

Comment: hmm, It's strange, but there is only one difference: and a writer, and a reader use `async_pipe` wrapper with the same name in my variant. Must a problem be in there? I launch all under Windows, reader and writer are two different unrelated process.

Comment: Looks like `async_pipe` assumes it will create the [pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) pair. This mean that if the pipe already exists it **shall** raise an error. ` what():  mkfifo() failed: File exists` The good news is, internally it will just use `posix_stream_descriptor`.

Comment: Yeah, I get this error. Well, it isn't supposed to use one `async_pipe` from and reading, and writing from the source code of it, which you gave me above. I don't know winapi well, but I didn't see `ConnectNamedPipe` call at the `async_pipe` class. I assume it is not being used the way I want it to be used (like analog of OS native named pipe)

Comment: On Win32 [create_named_pipe](https://github.com/boostorg/process/blob/develop/include/boost/process/detail/windows/async_pipe.hpp#L291). But I'd say you're out of luck if you wanted to create the pipe in two processes. You can suggest a feature to the library devs, perhaps.

Comment: May be :) Yeah, but after `create_named_pipe` it needs to call `ConnectNamedPipe` ([official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipes)), but this call is absent